# Angular - Check Azure SQL pool status before every API call

Tags: angular, azure, interceptor, azure-synapse

I have an angular application that communicates with Azure SQL pool through REST APIs. Azure SQL pool has a feature of going into Pause state after certain idle time. Therefore when a user makes a request and the SQL pool is paused, the request returns error.
I intend to implement a feature which does the below:

1. Whenever an api call is made from the angular app, the api to check the status of Azure SQL pool gets triggered and if the response says Paused state, make another API call to resume the status to Online.(implemented as observable and subscribed)
2. Later keep checking for the status until the status is Online (Implemented as observable and assigned to subscription to keep looking for emitted status)
3. Once the status is returned as Online, the actual api will be triggered.(to be implemented)

I need to know a way to make the check & resume operation before every api call is made. How can I implement it? I used interceptors but due to subscription that I have, return next.handle is not possible. I am able to make status check call, resume SQL pool call using interceptor. But waiting for status to become Online and make the original api call is challenging.
Any suggestions please? Thanks in advance.

Edit: The application requires user to confirm the resume operation via pop up if Azure SQL pool is in Pause state. If user confirms yes, Azure SQL pool is resumed.

Answer (score 0):

All this complications aren't needed. When you are using Azure SQL (I guess you use Serverless) and `SqlClient`, automatically `retry logic` is [available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/configurable-retry-logic-sqlclient-introduction). So, your Angular app need to call REST API implemented in .Net, leveraging SqlClient's built-in retry mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that: The application requires user to confirm the resume operation via pop up if Azure SQL pool is in Pause state. If user confirms yes, Azure SQL pool is resumed.

Comment: MS doc says SQL auto-resume can take `upto` 1 minute, since your requirement is for user to decide to whether resume the DB or not, you need to implement your REST api , which waits for DB to resume. In Angular app, after user confirms to resume, show a spinner icon and make blocking/sync REST API call.